# Why this regular expression shows safety?

Tags: regex, jsp

I have a JSP redemption for XSS attacks, in which it checks if the content matches a regular expression to determine whether it is safe or not, here is the code:

```
String contents = bodyContent.getString();
String regExp = new String("^\\w{5,25}$");
// Do a regex to find the good stuff
if (contents.matches(regExp)) {
     //write the original content
}else{
     //change content to make it safe and write it
}
```

My question is about the regular expression "^\w{5,25}$", which you can see it [here](http://www.strfriend.com/vis?re=%5E%5Cw%7B5,25%7D%24) visually. Why matching this regular expression shows safety?

Comment: Shouldn't that be ^\w{5,25}$ ?

Comment: *Why matching this regular expression shows safety?* -- Say what?

Comment: @aioobe: after all it turns out that this is not OP's own code and he is basically just asking what that regex is doing and why it would apparently ensure that it prevents from XSS attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the regular expression was:

```
 ^\w{5,25}$
```

then this would limit the string to letters, numbers and underscores - i.e. no spaces or other punctuation. This means that it cannot be a nefarious script as that would surely include spaces, or semi-colons.

Comment: Can you tell me why not less than 5 characters?

Comment: But the code says something else, it says a word with less than 5 characters, even without punctuations and spaces, may be harmful.

Comment: Sorry - yes - less than 5 characters will fail to match and so will be modified... can't explain that one - tbh - the whole concept is a bit odd, so I wouldn't worry too much about details - best bet is to replace with a better solution such as BalusC's answer.

Answer (score 3):

That railroad diagram is incorrect, "\w" is a regex special that matches so-called word characters. These are A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and underscores.

Input matching this is usually considered safe since it cannot include any of the normally used special or escape characters, but is by no means a guarantee.

Comment: Can you tell me why not less than 5 characters?

Comment: Can you tell me why you wrote the regex like that? Or was it after all just copypasted from some poor resource?

Comment: It was just copypasted, but not from a poor source I think. The source is the book "_Deadly Sins of Software Security_". It was offered by OWASP

Comment: @saeed: Not really, you haven't given any information on the purpose of the code beyond validating (validating what?). To me it looks like a form input validation that forces the user to input at least five characters, but no more than 25.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the concrete question which has already been answered by others, that's a plain wrong way to prevent your JSPs from XSS attacks. You should be just using JSTL `<c:out>` tag or `fn:escapeXml()` function to redisplay user-controlled data.

E.g.

```
<c:out value="${header['user-agent']}" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

This way HTML/XML special characters like `<`, `>` and so on won't be interpreted literally (which would cause a potential XSS hole), but will be escaped so that they get just displayed as-is.

This is behind the scenes just done by a literal char-by-char match and replace. All `<` are replaced by `&lt;`, all `>` are replaced by `&gt;`, all `"` are replaced by `&quot;` and so on. This does and should not involve regex.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not the answer of my question

Comment: I am aware of that. I am just answering what you *really* needed to achieve your functional requirement, not what you asked about the solution of which you tought that it is the right solution for your functional requirement. I am just trying to prevent that you go in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

You're matching a number of "word" characters, anchored to start and end of string. So we know there's no punctuation other than _ in that set.

Anything matching this set is deemed safe, I guess that the authors assume that nothing evil can be done in such a string.

I can't understand why less that 5 characters is deemed unsafe.

I don't see why if a string of 25 such characters is safe, 26 is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex validates that the string contains only the "word" character class, [a-Z0-9].  So, it is just validation that there is not punctuation or special characters in the string. It also validates for length, from 5 to 25.

An XSS attack commonly relies on a `<script>...</script>` routine getting inserted into the database - which obviously has a couple special characters [<>/].

Comment: Can you tell me why not less than 5 characters?

Comment: I assume the length criteria has nothing to do with XSS protection, and the app is just expecting valid input for that field to be longer than 5 characters.

Comment: There is nothing inherently unsafe about strings less than 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of why less than five characters would be "unsafe" is that if it was being used for a search query, 1 to 4 characters might return an excessive number of results. Many database-driven search functions require a minimum of 3-5 characters to avoid huge numbers of hits. Will this string be used for any sort of string matching?

Comment: No. It's an output string not an input. It's the string which will be shown on the page.